# Angular Material Text Input or Text Area Label Size Without Using Custom CSS or HTML(Using Framework Methods)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, label, size, angular-material

I want to increase the label size of the Angular Material text area without using any custom CSS or HTML. Probably there may be better ways of doing this using framework specific methods.

Please help

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the angular-material layout design example without custom css. Just wiht angular-material css class and directives. For further information you have to read this [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input).

```html
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak class="md-inline-form">
  <md-content md-theme="docs-dark" layout-gt-sm="row" layout-padding>
    <div>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input ng-model="user.title">
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input ng-model="user.email" type="email">
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
  </md-content>
  <md-content layout-padding>
    <div>
      <form name="userForm">
        <div layout-gt-xs="row">
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs>
            <label>Company (Disabled)</label>
            <input ng-model="user.company" disabled>
          </md-input-container>
          <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate" md-placeholder="Enter date">
          </md-datepicker>
        </div>
        <div layout-gt-sm="row">
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
            <label>First name</label>
            <input ng-model="user.firstName">
          </md-input-container>
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input ng-model="theMax">
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
          <label>Address</label>
          <input ng-model="user.address">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block">
          <input ng-model="user.address2" placeholder="Address 2">
        </md-input-container>
        <div layout-gt-sm="row">
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
            <label>City</label>
            <input ng-model="user.city">
          </md-input-container>
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
            <label>State</label>
            <md-select ng-model="user.state">
              <md-option ng-repeat="state in states" value="{{state.abbrev}}">
                {{state.abbrev}}
              </md-option>
            </md-select>
          </md-input-container>
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
            <label>Postal Code</label>
            <input name="postalCode" ng-model="user.postalCode" placeholder="12345" required ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{5}$/" md-maxlength="5">
            <div ng-messages="userForm.postalCode.$error" role="alert" multiple>
              <div ng-message="required" class="my-message">You must supply a postal code.</div>
              <div ng-message="pattern" class="my-message">That doesn't look like a valid postal code.
              </div>
              <div ng-message="md-maxlength" class="my-message">
                Don't use the long version silly...we don't need to be that specific...
              </div>
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
          <label>Biography</label>
          <textarea ng-model="user.biography" md-maxlength="150" rows="5" md-select-on-focus></textarea>
        </md-input-container>
      </form>
    </div>
  </md-content>
</div>
```